# Reg ex start with fixed string and end with variable number

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match these strings that start with fixed string  `These masters were created using` and end with variable `[space][name][space][char][number]`

```
These masters were created using Kevin O014
These masters were created using Jhon A039
These masters were created using Geeth P034
These masters were created using Jemes M077
These masters were created using Anne H058
These masters were created using JANE S345
```

Any idea?

I tried this  `^(These masters were created using).\s.[a-zA-Z].\s.[a-zA-Z].[0-9]{3}.$`. it gooks greek to me

Comment: Do you need to validate, or extract anything from these strings? Do you only need to work with English names, or any international names (containing letters like `ё`, for example), too?

Comment: Yes, I need to extract the last four chars `[char][number]`. FYI: I'm using C#. Only English I need to work with

Comment: I have revampled my answer to better fit your requirements. I would still prefer named capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
These masters were created using [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]\d+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG4gS8/2)

- `[a-zA-Z]+` To match a name (assuming, simple names, no `-`, no accentuated char)
- `[a-zA-Z]\d+` to match a letter followed by any digit. You might change to `[a-zA-Z]\d{3}` if you need exactly 3 digits

---

```
string input = @"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>These masters were created using Smith J054<br>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"These masters were created using [a-zA-Z]+ ([a-zA-Z]\d+)");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Found a match : " + match);
    if(match.Groups.Count >= 2)
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Extract " + match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output:

> Found a match : These masters were created using Smith J054
>
> Extract J054

Comment: it doesn't match `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>These masters were created using Smith J054<br>` :(

Comment: Just need to modify the last bit. I find it helpful to use online regex calculators.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya I removed the anchors, see edit, it matches now.

Answer (score 1):

^These masters were created using [[a-zA-z\S]* [[A-Za-z0-9]*$

Made sure it matches using multiline on an online calculator.

Answer (score 0):

To not only validate, but also to get the names and codes at the end, you can use

```
\bThese masters were created using (?<Name>[A-Za-z]+)\s+(?<Code>[A-Za-z][0-9]{3})\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbThese+masters+were+created+using+(%3f%3cName%3e%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b)%5cs%2b(%3f%3cCode%3e%5bA-Za-z%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d)%5cb&i=These+masters+were+created+using+Kevin+O014%0d%0aThese+masters+were+created+using+Jhon+A039%0d%0aThese+masters+were+created+using+Geeth+P034%0d%0aThese+masters+were+created+using+Jemes+M077%0d%0aThese+masters+were+created+using+Anne+H058%0d%0aThese+masters+were+created+using+JANE+S345&o=m)

where `(?<Name>[A-Za-z]+)` matches any 1+ ASCII letters and captures it into Group with name "Name", `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces, `(?<Code>[A-Za-z][0-9]{3})` matches and captures into Group "Code" a letter followed with 3 digits exactly (use `+` instead of `{3}` to match 1 or more digits).

Note that `\b` are word boundaries that help match the strings inside larger strings as whole words.

In C#:

```
var pattern = @"\bThese masters were created using (?<Name>\p{L}+)\s+(?<Code>\p{L}\d{3})\b";
```

[Sample C# demo](http://ideone.com/hfM1QT):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "aaaaaa These masters were created using Kevin O014\nThese masters were created using Jhon A039\nThese masters were created using Geeth P034\nThese masters were created using Jemes M077\nThese masters were created using Anne H058\nThese masters were created using JANE S345 aaaaa";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\bThese masters were created using (?<Name>[A-Za-z]+)\s+(?<Code>[A-Za-z][0-9]{3})\b")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m=> string.Format("{0}: {1}", m.Groups["Name"].Value, m.Groups["Code"].Value))
                    .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", matches));
    }
}
```